# Tampermonkey: Redirect URL not working in the Following Script

Tags: javascript, redirect, tampermonkey

I'm trying to make links get redirected automatically. For example, "http://laonple.blog.me/220676812642", which doesn't work, will be redirected to "https://blog.naver.com/laonple/220676812642" in ideal scenario. However, the following script doesn't work. Any thoughts on why this may be happening (and solution, too, if possible). Thank you!

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        Laonple
// @description Redirect
// @match       *://laonple.blog.me/*
// @grant       none
// @run-at      document-start
// @version     1.0
// ==/UserScript==

var number = location.pathname
var newHost = location.host.replace (/\laonple.blog.me$/, "blog.naver.com/laonple");
var newURL = location.protocol + "//" + newHost + number + location.search + location.hash;

location.replace (newURL);
```

Comment: By doesn't work, do you mean it doesn't redirect or redirects to the wrong URL?

Comment: Shouldn't the first line be **// ==UserScript==**?

Comment: it doesn't redirect at all. i've fixed the script displayed (copy pasting issue).

Answer (score 0):

There are some incorrect assumptions in your code. Understandable, but incorrect.

The correct approach is to find each `<a href` tag and modify it to have the new url (by changing the href attribute value).

Probably you will do something like this:

1. Use `querySelectorAll` to get a collection of all `a` tags on the page
2. Loop over that collection (e.g. forEach), and for each `a` tag, modify its href value:

```
const allATags = document.querySelectorAll('a');
allATags.forEach((el,idx) => {
   el.href = el.href.replace (/\laonple.blog.me$/, "blog.naver.com/laonple");;
});
```

Above code snippet is off-the-cuff, untested. *Caveat emptor.*